# Create array containing other declared variables in Fortran

Tags: arrays, fortran

I would like to create an array containing variables that have already been declared, so that I can loop through this array to access the elements by its index and carry out some operation. In Python, this would be easy. Say I want to create a `target_array`:

```
a = [3,4]
b = [5,6]

target_array = [a,b]

for ta in target_array:

    # some operation here
```

However, I am not sure how can I do this in Fortran. I tried the following:

```
real, dimension(2,2,2) :: a
real, dimension(2,2,2) :: b

real, parameter :: target_array = [a,b]
integer :: i
real, dimension(2,2,2) :: target_var

do i = 1,SIZE(target_array)
   
   target_var = target_array(i)

   ...

end do
```

However, I received the following error for the line where i declare `target_array`:

```
This symbol must be a defined parameter, an enumerator, or an argument of an inquiry function that evaluates to a compile-time constant.   [a]
```

Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your python code implicitly generates "array of arrays", where as in Fortran dimensions must be explicitly defined. So the following line does not make much sense:

```
target_array = [a,b]
```

`target_array` is scalar, where as `a` and `b` are vectors, so equivalence cannot apply. Additionally `target_array` has parameter attribute for some reason?

To achieve same as your python example try something like:

```
program main
  implicit none
  real, dimension(2,2,2)    :: a
  real, dimension(2,2,2)    :: b
  real, dimension(2,2,2,2)  :: target_array
  real                      :: target_var
  integer                   :: i, j, k, l

  target_array(:,:,:,1) = a
  target_array(:,:,:,2) = b

  do i = 1, size(target_array,DIM=4)
    do j = 1, size(target_array,DIM=3)
      do k = 1, size(target_array,DIM=2)
        do l = 1, size(target_array,DIM=2)
          target_var = target_array(l,k,j,i)
          ! ... 
        end do
      end do
    end do
  end do

end program main
```

Or alternatively in Fortran you can perform operations on a whole array e.g:

```
target_array(:,:,:,:) = target_array(:,:,:,:) * 2.0
```

Comment: When working with whole array operations, having the whole array slice notation `(:,:,:,:)` is not recommended, as the compiler has to often do extra work to determine the array bounds. Better and nicer to write `target_array = target_array * 2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

Derived types could help you here.

You could first define a derived type (let us call it `myVar_T`) that fits to what you describe as "variables that have already been declared". Then, you define the `target_array` variable as an array of type `myVar_T`.

Supposing that you want to work with rank 1 arrays of real numbers (as in the code snippet you posted), below is an example that compiles and runs. The strength of this method is that you can adapt it to variables that would be much more complex than small arrays of numbers.

```
program array_of_vars

implicit none

type :: myVar_T
  real, dimension(2) :: arr
end type

type(myVar_T), allocatable :: target_array(:)
real, dimension(2) :: target_val
integer :: target_array_length
integer :: iTarget
real :: mySum

target_array_length = 3
allocate(target_array( target_array_length ))

target_array(1)%arr = [3,4]
target_array(2)%arr = [5,6]
target_array(3)%arr = [7,8]

do iTarget = 1, target_array_length
   target_val = target_array(iTarget)%arr
   print *, target_val
   ! alternatively, you can use the variable directly:
   mySum = sum( target_array(iTarget)%arr )
   print *, mySum
end do

end program
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, this is an array-pointer version of BenBoulderite's code

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer i
    real, allocatable, target :: a(:), b(:)

    type ArrayPtr
        real, pointer :: ptr(:)
    endtype
    type(ArrayPtr), allocatable :: arrays(:)

    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4, 5]

    arrays = [ArrayPtr(a), ArrayPtr(b)]

    b(:) = b(:) + 100

    do i = 1, size(arrays)
        print *, i, " : ", arrays(i) % ptr
    enddo
end

!! gfortran-10 test.f90 && ./a.out
       1  :    1.00000000   2.00000000    
       2  :    103.000000   104.000000   105.000000
```

Here, `arrays` shares data with `a` and `b`, so the modification of the latter affects the contents of `arrays`. Because allocatable arrays (like `a`) are automatically deallocated at the end of subroutines etc, we need to make sure that the original arrays (like `a`) are kept alive when using `arrays` as array views.

The allocatable-array version below does not have this pitfall, but `arrays` have different data  from `a` and `b`, so the modification of the latter does not affect `arrays` (like `b` below).

```
program main
    implicit none
    integer i
    real, allocatable, target :: a(:), b(:)

    type ArrayVal
        real, allocatable :: dat(:)
    endtype
    type(ArrayVal), allocatable :: arrays(:)

    a = [1, 2]
    b = [3, 4, 5]

    arrays = [ArrayVal(a), ArrayVal(b)]

    b(:) = b(:) + 100

    do i = 1, size(arrays)
        print *, i, " : ", arrays(i) % dat
    enddo
end
!! gfortran-10 test.f90 && ./a.out
       1  :    1.00000000   2.00000000    
       2  :    3.00000000   4.00000000   5.00000000
```